# Control_RunDLL - Open sequential window?

Tags: windows, batch-file, tabs, window, command

I don't know if this is even possible, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

I know that you can append `,,tabnumber` to the end of a

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL
```

command to open a window on a specified tab, but is there a way to open a further window by programmatically selecting a button on that tab?

For example, I'm using

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL inetcpl.cpl,,4
```

to open Windows' Internet Properties window, but is there a way to programmatically to open the LAN Settings window from there, as LAN Settings doesn't seem to have its own process I can call directly.

(I plan to use this with things other than LAN Settings, if there is a solution, such as "Copy settings..." within the "Administrative" tab on the Region and Language window)

Comment: You can't append `,,tabnumber` to the end of an arbitrary rundll32 command, just the Control_RunDLL function in shell32.dll.  (Well, you *could*, but it wouldn't work.)

Comment: You're not really programming here.  You might have better luck on SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: There is no general mechanism for this. You are better off doing whatever you need programmatically instead of trying to drive the UI (which changes from version to version).

Comment: So, it's not possible then? Mkay. Post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`There is no general mechanism for this. You are better off doing whatever you need programmatically instead of trying to drive the UI (which changes from version to version). – Raymond Chen`